# Segmentation Fault during linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I am getting a segfault when I try and print out my linked list. Can anyone explain why? I am aware a segfault means that I am accessing memory I am not supposed to. I am assuming this means I am not setting up my pointers right. Any help would be great. My code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;             
}*head;

typedef struct node item;

int main() {

    item *curr, *head;

    head = NULL;

    char word = 'y';
    //int num[10];
    //int i = 0;

    while (word == 'y'){
    printf("Would you like to enter an integer? (y/n) ");
    scanf("%s", &word);

        if(word == 'y'){
            int temp = 0;
            printf("Enter an integer: ");
            scanf("%d", &temp);
            curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
            curr->val = temp;
            if (head == NULL){
                head = curr;
                head->next = NULL;
            }
            else {
            curr->next  = head;
            head = curr;
            }
        }
    }

    curr = head;

    while(curr != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", curr->val); //seg fault happens here
        curr = curr->next ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when defining the struct, why is it *head?

Comment: You're right, it compiles and works perfectly in GCC. Must be something with Xcode. Looks like I will finish this out in Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I actually took the *head out. That was from before when I was using a typedef in my struct declaration.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
scanf("%s", &word);
```

is a buffer overflow, since `%s` will read a *string*, but you only have a single character. This invokes undefined behavior; even if you enter just a single character, `scanf()` will add 0-termination after that character to make a proper string.

Change the declaration of `word`:

```
char word[32];
```

And scan with an explicit size, to prevent `scanf()` from writing outside the buffer:

```
scanf("%30s", word);
```

Also check the return values of all I/O and memory allocation calls, since they can fail.

Finally, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`, in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the memory leaks, can I suggest you fix them with the following code:

```
while(curr != NULL) {
    item* temp = curr; // store the current pointer
    printf("%d\n", curr->val);
    curr = curr->next ;
    free(temp); //free the current one now that curr points to the next
}
```

This frees the already printed `head` in each iteration of the loop.

The other issues are already addressed by other posters.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `*head` pointer as

```
item *curr=NULL, *head = NULL;
```

without this, the `if` will not execute and you would access some random memory for `head` node. The `while` loop for printing the linked list may not terminate and keep accessing invalid memory.

```
if (head == NULL){ 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been caught out by `scanf`. First you wish to read a single *character* and the format for that is `%c` - `%s` reads the next non-blank sequence of characters *after* skipping any leading whitespace. Using `%s` causes the error, as it overwrites memory.

However if you change the format to `%c` your code still won't work, and it's `scanf` again. For most formats `scanf` will skip leading whitespace, but it does **not** do this when reading characters. So if you run your code you will see this:

```
Would you like to enter an integer? (y/n) y
Enter an integer: 10
Would you like to enter an integer? (y/n) 10
```

The second time around `scanf` has read the newline after the `10` into `word`, that is not a `y`, and then moved on to print out your list - the `10` at the end.

To skip whitespace *before* a character you add a space into the format string, so the line becomes:

```
scanf(" %c", &word);
```

That one change will allow your code to work but you should really do more checking. `scanf` will return the number of items it successfully found, you should check that to make sure the user really did enter a number etc., etc. As an example here is what happens if the user accidentally enters `y` twice:

```
Would you like to enter an integer? (y/n) y
Enter an integer: y
Would you like to enter an integer? (y/n) Enter an integer:
```

What has happened here is `scanf("%d", &temp)` failed, returned `0`, and stored nothing into `temp`. However as you did not check the result your program continues and then the second `y` is consumed by the next `scanf(" %c", &word)`.

Also look at your `if (head == NULL)` statement - this is not really necessary at all, you can replace the whole `if`/`else` with just two lines... that is left as an exercise.

HTH